# json_encode issue when parsing array with portuguese character in php

Tags: php, web-services, json

I have result array as below

```
$array = array(array('nome'=>'Paição','cidade'=>'São Paulo'),array('nome'=>'Paição','cidade'=>'São Paulo'));
```

when i encode same array with json_encode in php it not return as same as array and it return as below json string

```
$json = json_encode($array);
$result = [{"nome":"Pai\u00e7\u00e3o","cidade":"S\u00e3o Paulo"},{"nome":"Pai\u00e7\u00e3o","cidade":"S\u00e3o Paulo"}]
```

Please anyone have idea to convert this array as same characters in php

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using utf-8 encoding?

Comment: Which version of php are you using ?

Comment: yes i am using utf-8 encoding,
and i m using PHP Version 5.2.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for who use below 5.4 php version,

```
$arr = array(array('nome'=>'Paição','cidade'=>'São Paulo'),array('nome'=>'Paição','cidade'=>'São Paulo'));

$array = preg_replace("/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/e", "iconv('UCS-4LE','UTF-8',pack('V', hexdec('U$1')))", json_encode($arr));
```

Result of above is same as passed value

```
[{"nome":"Paição","cidade":"São Paulo"},{"nome":"Paição","cidade":"São Paulo"}]
```

and you have to also set mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); after mysql connection.

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`**](https://www.php.net/json_encode) in the json_encode.

Do like this

```
<?php
$array = array(array('nome'=>'Paição','cidade'=>'São Paulo'),array('nome'=>'Paição','cidade'=>'São Paulo'));
$json = json_encode($array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo $json;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but giving error Notice: Use of undefined constant JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE - assumed 'JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE' and i have php 5.3.10 version.

is anyone has any solution between php 5.2 to 5.4 version excpet JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function wrapping the whole json_encode():

```
utf8_encode(json_encode());
```

On the other hand, if what you're doing is sending and parsing data from mysql you should define the connection to utf8:

```
$conn=  mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8');
```